# How to apply HTML style or font weight for custom field "name" (not for value)

Tags: jira, custom-fields, jira-plugin

I've created a JIRA custom field plugin where i want to allow for custom field name to appear as bold text or can apply style. what should i modify to achieve this.

example:

add custom field - name is "sumary text"

so, on screen, it will appear as "summary text: "

here, i want "summary text" should be bolder or with some style.

Is it possible on JIRA custom field configuration or , can i handle such in plugin stuff ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

As found, it should be achievable though jquery apply at custom field's description.
First look at that custom field in firebug and then apply css, it is mostly appear as below :

```
AJS.$("#rowForcustomfield_XXXXX .name").html(null)  //if want to remove label
AJS.$("#rowForcustomfield_XXXXX .name").css(style)  //prepare style object and apply or style
```

(apply above script in custom field >> description)

(there is no any way in configuration as JIRA allows custom field with label name and value.)